# Javascript errors in modal box

Tags: javascript

This works in Venobox modal box but in PrettyPhoto I am getting errors.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  
var buVideo = document.getElementById("bVideo");
    
function playPause() {
  var el = document.getElementById("playButton");
  if (buVideo.paused) {
    buVideo.play();
    el.className ="";
  } else {
    buVideo.pause();
    el.className = "playButton";
  }
}
buVideo.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
</script>
    
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <video id="bVideo" controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
  <div id="playButton" class="playButton" onclick="playPause()"></div>
</div>
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: playPause is not defined
>           at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tried:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var buVideo = document.getElementById("bVideo");
}
```

but still the same error. Tried to put script before and after `<div class="video-wrapper"></div>` but it doesn't help.

Comment: This : `onclick="playPause()" ` is redundant. You have already bound the click listener to your `playPause` function with `buVideo.addEventListener`

Comment: When I move your code to after it seens to work (at least its not throwing an error). Placing it before will fail, as the element with the desired `id` does not exist yet.

Comment: Somethingthere, yes it works in a normal webpage and in Venobox modal. For some reason it does not work in PrettyPhoto lightbox.